# How to add oracle TRUNC(SYSDATE-100,'Q') to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, datetime-format

I have MySQL installed and I have an oracle script with me and I create schemas and tables and stuck with trunc and quarter in oracle and want them to insert in MySQL.

how to use trunc and q while inserting into mysql?

```
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT (ASSIGNMENT_ID, CONSULTANT_ID,CLIENT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,PAY,COMMENTS) 
  VALUES (1, 2, 1, date_format(quarter(SYSDATE()-100),'%d-%b-%Y'),date_format(quarter(SYSDATE()-100),'%d-%b-%Y')+31,500, null);

date_format(quarter(SYSDATE()-100),'%d-%b-%Y'),date_format(quarter(SYSDATE()-100),'%d-%b-%Y')+31,500
```

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '4' Error Code: 1292.
>   Incorrect date value: 'Q' for column 'start_date' at row 1 Error Code:
>   1292. Incorrect date value: 'Q' for column 'start_date' at row 1

Comment: SELECT QUARTER(SYSDAte()-100);  returns 4, so that is no chance to form it like this to a date with '%d-%b-%Y',

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
set @former_day = date_add( sysdate(), interval -100 day );

select
date_format(@former_day ,'%Y-01-01') + interval quarter(@former_day)-1 quarter 
as new_date
```

to generate what you want.

- to get the beginning of the current year for 100 days before :

  `date_format(@former_day ,'%Y-01-01')`
- to add the number of quarters to the beginning of the quarter for 100
  days before :

  `+ interval quarter(@former_day)-1 quarter`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4d33e9a4604066c25e44595c773f2463)</kbd>